# Prolog: Appending a List fails and Not too sure why

Tags: list, prolog, append

I am relatively new to prolog and what I am trying to do is create a list, but I seem to be encountering an error and Im not too sure why.

Here is the trace for a more detailed outlook, This is part of a natural langue parser.

Exit: (75,513) adj(womens) ? creep

Call: (75,513) lists:append(_G5921885, [adj(womens)], _G5921887) ? creep

Exit: (75,513) lists:append([], [adj(womens)], [adj(womens)]) ? creep

Call: (75,513) np2([heptathlon, winner, was, an, athlete], _G5921869, _G5921887, [], [adj(womens)]) ?

so... at first every is OK and gets added to the list but when it tries to add a second item to the list this happens....

Call: (75,514) adj(heptathlon) ? creep

Exit: (75,514) adj(heptathlon) ? creep

Call: (75,514) lists:append([], [adj(heptathlon)], [adj(womens)]) ? creep

Fail: (75,514) lists:append([], [adj(heptathlon)], [adj(womens)]) ? creep

Here is the code that appends the list:

append(List,[adj(H)],TargetList),

np2(T,Rest,Rem,List,TargetList).

If anyone could share some light on where I am going wrong and how to solve it that would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right here:

```
Call: (75,514) lists:append([], [adj(heptathlon)], [adj(womens)])
```

This cannot succeed, because the definition of `append/3` contradicts it.

> append(*?List1*, *?List2*, *?List1AndList2*):
>
> *List1AndList2* is the concatenation of *List1* and *List2*

In your case, *List1* is the empty list `[]`, so *List1andList2* should be the same as *List2*, but it isn't. I don't really know the logic of your program to help further. If you are trying to use `append/3` to append *List1* and *List2* (as opposed to for example splitting *List1andList2*) you should make sure that *List1andList2* is an uninstantiated variable at the time of the call to `append/3`.